# Help with creating a dialog and passing info to it

Tags: android

I have created a screen with 5 rows of information. each row has 2 values. (`value1` and `value2`)
At the end of each row is a button. For each row I have created a xml file that I am looping though and filling in the values from a database

what I am looking at doing is when the button is pressed a dialog is opened with two editviews filled in with the values from that row

Then when the button is pressed on the dialog the values are updated in database.

I am having problems with the `createdialog` / `preparedialog` methods and passing the values to them.

UPDATE with Code

```
public void createLayout(LinearLayout pMainlayout, String pMajorValue) {

        DatabaseTools db = new DatabaseTools(this);

        majorValue= pMajorValue;

        nameInfo = db.getNames(pMajorValue);
        name = returnName(pMajorValue);

        LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        for (int i = 0; i < nameInfo.size(); i++) {
            // Get views
            View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainlayout, null);
            TextView nameView = (TextView) sightmarkView.findViewById(R.id.name_title);
            TextView Value1View = (TextView) sightmarkView.findViewById(R.id.value1);
            TextView ValueView = (TextView) sightmarkView.findViewById(R.id.value2);

            Button updateButton = (Button) sightmarkView.findViewById(R.id.updatebutton);

        // Get info from Database
            nameValue = nameInfo.get(i).toString();
            value1v = db.getMark(majorValue,  nameInfo.get(i).toString());
                value2v = db.getMark(majorValue,  nameInfo.get(i).toString());
            // populate info into fields
            nameView.setText(nameValue);
            Value1View.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
            Value2View.setText(String.valueOf(value2));

            updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            //Code here to add values to a bundle

                            showDialog(SIGHTMARK_DIALOG_ID, bundle);

                        }
                    });

            pMainlayout.addView(view);
        }

    }
```

All this work correctly. The values are displayed. I have looked into using a bundle to pass them into the dialog

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        switch(id) {
        case DIALOG_ID:
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.update));
            final EditText value1Edit = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.value1_current);
            final EditText value2Edit = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.value2_current);

        //next pull values from bundle to populate into fields  

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setView(layout);
            // Now configure the AlertDialog
            builder.setTitle(R.string.sight_update_title);
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    this.removeDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    value1New = Float.parseFloat(value1Edit.getText().toString());
                    value2New = Float.parseFloat(value2Edit.getText().toString());

                // method run to update the database with the new values passed to it
                    updateMarks(value1, value2);

                    this.removeDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });
            // Create the AlertDialog and return it
            AlertDialog Dialog = builder.create();
            return Dialog;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This part has issues and is not getting the values correctly or passing them to the update method

Comment: What have you tried so far and what do you think is not working? You'll need to show some code and layout files before anybody has a chance of helping.

Comment: can home a global static variable and assign the needed value when the button is clicked and then you can use that value to fill the editview in your dialog...

Comment: Main part of my issue is passing the the two values to createdislog / preparedislog. I can provide code if nessary. At the moment I have the alertdialog opening up correctly but has blank values in it. Thanks

Comment: If you can supply code, that would be helpful. @Dinash - global variables are almost always unnecessary.

Comment: @James show your code so that we could help you solve your problem...

Comment: added code, sorry for not being as short as it should be. wanted to get what I am doing across. Thanks

Comment: You need to post the code that gets the values from the Bundle in onCreateDialog.  Also, the code looks like it doesn't compile, e.g. where are value1 and value2 defined as passed into updateMarks(value1, value2)?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is here:

> If you use showDialog(int), the activity will call through to this
>   method the first time, and hang onto it thereafter. Any dialog that is
>   created by this method will automatically be saved and restored for
>   you, including whether it is showing.

remove references

```
removeDialog(SIGHTMARK_DIALOG_ID);
showDialog(SIGHTMARK_DIALOG_ID, bundle);
```

[documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29)